# Crude oil benchmarks and production places

Tags: international-trade, oil

I discovered recently that there are 3 main price indicators for crude oil (used by the IMF): *WTI*, *Dubaï*, and *UK Brent*. If I understand correctly, each place trades some specific kind of oil (with more or less sulfur among other), which is related to the production place.

Is there some stylized facts, or a precise matrix available, which relate the production place and the price index?

My first guess was OPEC production $\Rightarrow$ *Dubai* and US production $\Rightarrow$ *WTI* but I'm not sure regarding the *UK Brent*...

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.oxfordenergy.org/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/August2006-MiddleEastCrud-Pricing-BassamFattouh.pdf) states:

> Brent, WTI and Dubai-Oman are the main crude oil benchmarks of 
>   the current oil pricing system. Nearly all oil traded outside America and the Far East is priced using Brent as a benchmark. WTI is the main benchmark used for pricing oil imports  into  the  USA.  Dubai-Oman  is  used  as  a  benchmark  for Gulf  crudes (Saudi Arabia, Iran, Iraq, the UAE, Qatar and Kuwait) sold in the Asia-Pacific market.

Regarding where the oil is produced, according to [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/102314/understanding-benchmark-oils-brent-blend-wti-and-dubai.asp):

> “Brent” actually refers to oil from four different fields in the North Sea: Brent, Forties, Oseberg and Ekofisk. [...] WTI refers to oil extracted from wells in the U.S. and sent via pipeline to Cushing, Oklahoma. [...] [Dubai-Oman is a] “basket” product consisting of crude from Dubai, Oman or Abu Dhabi.

The above is sometimes visualised in the following map:

[image]